# Convert arrow function, old question closed without aid, 'duplicates' were not useful

Tags: javascript

I've got a bit of a code that works fine as an arrow function, but using wkhtmltopdf converting a webpage to an image, it's unable to read arrow functions. That said, I've tried numerous times to make this function without the arrow, but no success yet.

The 'related' answers do not answer my question. I simply can't get this function to return the same data when I remove the arrow for this async function.

Babel transpiler seems unable to do this, as well.

```
function getJSON(url, token) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
        if (token != null){
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        }
        xhr.responseType = "json";
        xhr.onload = function() {
        var status = xhr.status;
        if (status === 200) {
            resolve(xhr.response);
        }
        else {
            reject(xhr.status);
        }
        };
        xhr.send();
    });
}
```

Comment: What's the actual issue you are facing? I can see the issue is related to the Promise as response that you are not able to retrieve data but get Promise instead?

Comment: Can you also add the part of code where you will call `getJSON()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you please try this:

```
function getJSON(url, token) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    if (token != null) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
    }
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = function () {
      var status = xhr.status;
      if (status === 200) {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      } else {
        reject(xhr.status);
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
  });
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked. I was adding the `function` to the wrong portion of the code. This allows wkhtmltopdf to work, but unfortunately it still can't process async functions for some reason. Maybe an older parser that it uses. You solved my issue, though!